# How to print actual unicode characters in python dict or list

Tags: python, utf-8, python-unicode, utf8mb4

Please consider the following code

```
a = 'abc ™ def'
print a
di = {"k":a}
print di
```

When I print a variable, it will print the ™ symbol properly. But, when I print di, it will print the following

```
{'k': 'abc \xe2\x84\xa2 def'}
```

Why So ?

Further If I print di["k"], then it will print ™ symbol properly.

My requirement is that I want to print di with proper symbols as it is

How to do so ?

Comment: Why is this a requirement? This is simply how the `dict` string is defined, it uses the `__repr__` of the objects it contains

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga actually I have a big complex dict and I want to write it to file as string.....

Comment: You shouldn't use the `str` representation of a complex dict for persistence anyway. Use JSON, or even pickle at least.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga json.dumps(di) is not working....could you please give an example

Comment: "Is not working" is not enough of a problem specification. Edit your question and include a [mcve].